# Use touchable/virtual keyboard with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm deploying a react application that will run over PanelPC, so without keyboard.

In other part of code I use `react-touch-screen-keyboard` https://github.com/xtrinch/react-touch-screen-keyboard to show a virtual keyboard on pressing some input field.
Now I need to use it within `react-select` https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select but I don't know if is possible and how..

Anyone have already done something similar? Or have you an alternative to `react-select` that works with touch screen keyboard?

Thanks

Paolo

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever find a solution? I've tried triggering keyboard events, but no luck so far.

Comment: Not yet..I will try different alternatives in this days..I'll update you if I have some news..

Comment: I got react-select@2.0 working with https://github.com/srm985/mok-project. I made a react component wrapper and changed the source code so I could use it as a controlled component, with a callback for keypresses.